# How to create a column based on ttest using names from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

My df:

```
                            decile 0                  decile 9
                     mean median       std     mean median        std
assets           2.666667    3.0  1.527525     7.75    8.0   1.258306
age              4.666667    3.0  4.725816     7.25    5.0   5.251984
diversification  1.333333    1.0  1.527525    13.50    2.0  24.351591
many...
additional...
variables...
```

I want to add an additional column which tests the difference in means. Basically, I want

```
ttest_ind(master[master.decile==9]['assets'], master[master.decile==0]['assets'])
```

for the first entry, and

```
ttest_ind(master[master.decile==9]['assets'], master[master.decile==0]['assets'])
```

for the second entry. I do not want to manually create a column bc I have many variables and might arrange the order later.

desired output:

```
decile                     decile 0                  decile 9
                     mean median       std     mean median        std    mean difference
assets           2.666667    3.0  1.527525     7.75    8.0   1.258306         xxx
age              4.666667    3.0  4.725816     7.25    5.0   5.251984         xxx
diversification  1.333333    1.0  1.527525    13.50    2.0  24.351591         xxx
many...
additional...
variables...
```

Comment: could you provide your df as a dictionary? MultiIndex dfs are difficult to read from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

IUUC, you can just locate the index and column

```py
def ttest_ind(idx):
    master.loc[idx, 'mean_difference'] = master.loc[idx, ('decile 9', 'mean')] - master.loc[idx, ('decile 0', 'mean')]
    master.loc[idx, ('difference', 'mean')] = master.loc[idx, ('decile 9', 'mean')] - master.loc[idx, ('decile 0', 'mean')]

ttest_ind('assets')
```

```
                  decile 0                  decile 9                   mean_difference difference
                     mean median       std    mean median        std                       mean
assets           2.666667    3.0  1.527525    7.75    8.0   1.258306        5.083333   5.083333
age              4.666667    3.0  4.725816    7.25    5.0   5.251984             NaN        NaN
diversification  1.333333    1.0  1.527525   13.50    2.0  24.351591             NaN        NaN
```

But you can also subtract one sub column in one time

```py
master[('difference', 'std')] = master[('decile 9', 'std')] - master[('decile 0', 'std')]
```

```
                  decile 0                  decile 9                   difference
                     mean median       std    mean median        std        std
assets           2.666667    3.0  1.527525    7.75    8.0   1.258306  -0.269219
age              4.666667    3.0  4.725816    7.25    5.0   5.251984   0.526168
diversification  1.333333    1.0  1.527525   13.50    2.0  24.351591  22.824066
```

Even subtract the whole multi-level columns

```
master = master.join(master[['decile 9']].sub(master['decile 0'].values).rename(columns={'decile 9':'difference'}))
```

```
                  decile 0                  decile 9                   difference
                     mean median       std    mean median        std       mean median        std
assets           2.666667    3.0  1.527525    7.75    8.0   1.258306   5.083333    5.0  -0.269219
age              4.666667    3.0  4.725816    7.25    5.0   5.251984   2.583333    2.0   0.526168
diversification  1.333333    1.0  1.527525   13.50    2.0  24.351591  12.166667    1.0  22.824066
```